# A path to combinatorics: proving that there are at least 2 people who have same number of people between them

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

"An even number of persons are seated around a table. After a break, they are again seated around the same table, not necessarily in the same places. Prove that at least two persons have the same number of persons between them as before the break."

I don't think I have a proof, but I just want to get the feedback on my approach/idea. I have not looked at the solution on the book. Thank you in advance!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't post unsearchable pictures.  Instead typeset in *MathJax*.

Comment: Don't write "assume the statement posed in the question is false". Instead, write the statement which you're assuming to be false, i.e. "Assume that there is no pair of people such that...", and why you're assuming that, e.g. to force a contradiction. When you write "statement posed in the question" you're forcing the reader to go back to the question and break the flow of your exposition.

Comment: If I understand correctly your write-up, you show that there exists a pair of people such that there is the same number of persons between them, i.e. $n-1$ on both sides. But as I understand it, this is not what the problem is asking. The problem is asking to prove that there is at least one pair of people such that if there are $r$ and $l$ people between them, then after a reshuffle there are again $r$ and $l$ people between the same pair.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Randy. Do you think I can still use the result I got (that there exists a pair of people that have same number of persons between them) to prove the problem? Or is my entire approach (using subsets and "pairing" method) is wrong?

Comment: I think the fact that there are exactly $n$ pairs of oppositely sitting people does not need an elaborated proof. Besides it is not clear what is the role of the break in your proof. If you are going to prove that there is necessarily a pair of the same oppositely sitting people before and after the break - this is not true.

Comment: With problems like these it is always useful to start first with an explicit low value of $n$, e.g $2n=4$ is the smallest non-trivial value, and prove it for $2n=4$. Then increase to $2n=6$ and try to figure out if there is a general principle. Pairings will have to be used at some point, but you also have to account for the rearrangement of seating, so some sort of a permutation will be involved. @user  gave a solution in the answer below and I highly recommend to go through their answer by choosing a low value for $n$ and compute everything manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with a comment that you wrongly understood the problem, which in reality asks if there is a pair of persons such that there is exactly same number of people between them before and after the break.

The problem is essentially about the permutation which sends $i\mapsto\sigma(i)$. We would like to prove that there are at least two indicies $i,j$, such that
$$
j-i=\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)\iff \sigma(i)-i=\sigma(j)-j.
$$
To avoid the problem with sign we may count the difference always in the same direction (say counterclockwise): $\delta(i)=(\sigma(i)-i)\pmod{2n}$. With this definition $\delta(i)$ can take the values $0,1,\dots 2n-1$.

Assume that there are no two persons that have the same number of people before and after the break: $$\forall i\ne j:\; \delta(i)\ne\delta(j).\tag1$$ This means that $\delta(i)$ takes **all** values from $0$ to $2n-1$, so that:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\delta(i)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}k=n(2n-1)\equiv n\pmod {2n}.\tag2
$$

But on the other hand since $\sigma(i)$ is the same set as $i$ it should be
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\delta(i)\equiv0\pmod {2n}.\tag3
$$

Since (2) and (3) cannot hold simultaneously the assumption (1) was wrong.

Comment: Hi! I was not able to solve this problem so I read your answer and tried to think about it for a long time but I am still confused about one thing, You say "We would like to prove that there are at least two indicies $i,j$, such that $j-i=\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)$".... But, don't we actually need to prove that their exists at least two indicies $i,j$ such that $|j-i|=|\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)|$, as we only need their 'distance' apart to be equal, not 'signed distance'; for instance imagine two people were sitting on seats 3 and 5 and now they move to 6 and 4 respectively, their distance apart (contd...)

Comment: is same but $2 \neq -2$. So this would render the whole proof wrong. Even the book I was reading had the exact same solution, so I am very confused now, could you please help me understand the solution?

Comment: @Aditya_math You are correct and wrong simultaniously. I have proved a stronger result: "Prove that at least two persons have the same number of persons between them as before the break, the number of persons being counted in both cases in the same direction from the first person to the second one". Therefore the proof would not render wrong.